# Как пропустить ошибку при парсинге, если на странице нет заданного элемента?

Tags: python, парсер, исключения, bs4, exception-handler

Есть парсер сайта, название мероприятия, дата, локация и цена берется из карточек, но не у всех карточек есть цена, и тут возникает ошибка `'list index out of range'`, и карточка не выводит другие значения которые есть?

ошибка возникает при попытке извлечения текста из `fest_price`

**Пример кода:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
# from proxy_auth import proxies
import json

# https://www.skiddle.com/festivals/search/?sort=0&fest_name=&from_date=1%20Nov%202022&to_date=&maxprice=500

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

# collect all  fests URLs:
fests_urls_list = []
for i in range(0, 120, 24):
# for i in range(0, 24, 24):
    url = f"https://www.skiddle.com/festivals/search/?ajaxing=1&sort=18&fest_name=&from_date=1%20Nov%202022&to_date=&maxprice=500&o={i}&bannertitle="

    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    json_data = json.loads(req.text)
    html_response = json_data["html"]

    with open(f"data/index_{i}.html", "w") as file:
        file.write(html_response)

    with open(f"data/index_{i}.html") as file:
        src = file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    cards = soup.find_all("a", class_="card-details-link")

    for item in cards:
        fest_url = "https://www.skiddle.com" + item.get("href")
        fests_urls_list.append(fest_url)

# collect fest info
count = 0
fest_list_result = []
for url in fests_urls_list[0:3]:
    count += 1
    # print(count)
    # print(url)

    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
        fest_name = soup.find("h1").text
        fest_info_block = soup.find("div", class_="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2 css-1ik2gjq")

        fest_date = fest_info_block.find("span") and fest_info_block.find_next().text
        fest_location = fest_info_block.find("span").find_next().find_next().text
        # fest_location = fest_info_block.find_all("span")[2].text

        fest_price = fest_info_block.find_all("span")[3].text

        print(fest_name)
        print(fest_date)
        print(fest_location)
        print(fest_price)
        print("#" * 20)

        #get contact details and info

        # fest_list_result.append(
        #     {
        #         "Name": fest_name,
        #         "Date": fest_date,
        #         "Location": fest_location,
        #         "Price": fest_price
        #     }
        # )

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print("Error")

with open("fest_list_result.json", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(fest_list_result, file, indent=4,  ensure_ascii=False)
```

Как сделать проверку чтоб при отсутствии `fest_price = fest_info_block.find_all("span")[3].text`, его просто пропускали, но при этом другие данные выводились?

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    fest_price = fest_info_block.find_all("span")[3].text
    print(fest_price)
except Exception as E:
    print('Error: there is no fest_price!\n', E)
finally:
    print(fest_name)
    print(fest_date)
    print(fest_location)
    print("#" * 20)
```

Или если эти данные потом пойдут в таблицу, то, возможно будет удобнее ставить прочерк (или что-нибудь другое) вместо `fest_price`, если его нет:

```
try:
    fest_price = fest_info_block.find_all("span")[3].text
except Exception as E:
    print('Error: there is no fest_price!\n', E)
    fest_price = '-'
finally:
    print(fest_price)
    print(fest_name)
    print(fest_date)
    print(fest_location)
    print("#" * 20)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если вам помог ответ - нажмите кнопку принять ответ